# Saving frontend form data in wordpress

Tags: forms, front-end

I have front-end user form like,

- Title
- Image Upload
- Drop Down Category
- Description
- Tag

Now when a user fills the form and hits the publish button from the front-end..... at the back-end a post is created with title and all the details, im able to create a post with post title and the description, but im unable to save the category, tag. and how to add category and tags to the columns

[image]

For image upload i searched for solutions but nothing helped, the code is

```
<form id="new_post"<?php do_action('post_edit_form_tag'); ?> name="new_post" method="post" action="">

                    <!-- post name -->
                    <p><label for="title">Title</label><br />
                    <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title" />
                    </p>

                    <!-- post Category -->
                    <p><label for="Category">Parent:</label><br />
                    <?php 
                        wp_dropdown_categories('type=product&show_count=0&selected=-1&hierarchical=1&depth=1&hide_empty=0&exclude=0&show_option_none=Select Gender&name=main_prod&taxonomy=product_cat');
                    ?>
                    </p>
                    <!-- Image Upload -->
                    <p><label for="description">Image Upload</label><br />
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
                    <br />

                    <!-- post Content -->
                    <p><label for="description">Content</label><br />
                    <textarea id="description" tabindex="3" name="description" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
                    </p>

                    <!-- post tags -->
                    <p><label for="post_tags">Tags:</label></br>
                    <input type="text" value="" tabindex="5" size="16" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" /></p>
                    <p align="right"><input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>

                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <?php
                    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

                        // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
                        if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
                            $title =  $_POST['title'];
                        } else {
                            echo 'Please enter a  title';
                        }
                        if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
                            $description = $_POST['description'];
                        } else {
                            echo 'Please enter the content';
                        }
                        $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

                        // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
                        $new_post = array(
                         'post_title'    => $title,
                         'post_content'  => $description,

                         'post_category' => array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
                         'tags_input'    => array($tags),
                         'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
                         'post_type' => 'product'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
                        ); 
                        //save the new post
                        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
                        //insert taxonomies
                    }
```

in functions.php

/////////////////////////// file upload function ///////////////////////

```
add_action( 'post_edit_form_tag' , 'post_edit_form_tag' );

function post_edit_form_tag( ) {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}
```

i dont want to use any plugins, any ideas plz

Comment: "i dont want to use any plugin" ... ugh. Isn't your code in a plugin or theme already... ?

Comment: @kaiser no kaiser..... without any plugin involvement im writing the logic manually.....as my client doesn't want plugins. can this be done

Comment: I know you don't want to use a plugin. And you've probably done your research, but if you haven't seen this, [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/features/form-builder/) does what you want to do.

Comment: "Plugin", "Dropins", "MU-Plugins", "Themes" is just an organizational wrapper for files. Nothing else. They got nothing to do with security, performance or anything. It's just the convention where to put your files. Period. So: WHERE are you putting above code?

Comment: @kaiser i created a template page for user, so in the User template page im writing this code

Comment: @user801773 i have seen the gravity forms, yeah it completes my task but as i said can this be done without plugin

Answer (score 2):

Also, how are you processing your image upload? That function only sets the enctype.

By adding the following beneath your call to `wp_insert_post` you will be able to process your image upload,

```
if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
}
     if ($_FILES) {
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
            if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
            }
            $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $pid );
            add_post_meta($pid, 'meta_key_to_attach_image_to', $attach_id, false);
            continue;

        if ($attach_id > 0){
            //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
            update_post_meta($pid,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as you know WordPress does not have the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute which is required for file uploading. So yeah in my code i didnt write logic for the uploaded image, can you guide me where to keep this <?php wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $file ); ?>  and what args should i pass in the function, kindly bare with me

Comment: Paste the snippet shown beneath your call to `wp_insert_post`, you do not need to include the line `add_post_meta` if you are not uploading the file to a meta field, however the `update_post_meta` function is necessary to receive the attachment ID processed by `media_handle_upload` so it can attach it to your post/thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

Add this after save new post:

```
//Set the object terms after when we have the ID
wp_set_post_terms( $new_post, $tags, 'post_tag' );
```

This will save your tags.